# Why can't I name a function `next` - 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

I've created a simple class and named one of the methods `next` which is failing when called.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = 0

    def next(self, obj):
        self.next = obj
```

Execution code:

```
a = Node(1)
b = Node(2)
a.next(b)       <-TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

However, I'm getting `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Any other names other than `next` work fine, even built-ins as 'object' / 'range' didn't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You overwrote the value of `next` in the constructor: you *had* a function named `next`, but replaced that function with 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple!

You have initialized **next** as an integer:

> self.next = 0

And after that, you're trying to call it as a function. Just rename the function or the member.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove self.next=0, because you define self.next is int type, you next function input obj type, is error

```
In [18]: class Node():
    ...:     def __init__(self, val):
    ...:         self.val = val
    ...:
    ...:     def next(self, obj):
    ...:         self.next = obj
    ...:

In [19]: a = Node(1)

In [20]: b = Node(2)

In [21]: a.next(b)

In [22]: a.next.val
Out[22]: 2
```